# Determine whether the following functions defined on a set of real numbers are one-to one:

Tags: functions

I have this question but I think I am doing it wrong, can anyone point out my mistake. I could also like to ask when the question says "defined on a set of all real numbers x" is this information necessary? Thanks!

Determine whether the following functions defined on a set of real numbers are one-to one:

f(x) = 1/(x^2 + 1)for all real numbers x.

My Attempt:
 [image]

Edited the question, it should be f(x) = 1/(x^2 + 1)

Comment: is $f(x)= \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ ? or $f(x)= \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Comment: In the second to last lines, you should find

$$x_{1}x_{2}(x_{2} - x_{1}) - (x_{2} - x_{1}) = (x_{2} - x_{1})(x_{1}x_{2} - 1) = 0$$

and what does this tell you?

Comment: sorry I didn't realise I type wrongly, should be f(x) = 1/(x^2 + 1)

Comment: then it is  not injective because $f(1)=f(-1)= 1/2$

Comment: @Mattos thanks I saw my mistake.

Comment: It is necessary to say that the function is defined on the set of real numbers. For suppose the domain of the function was $\{0\}$, then the function is one-one and if the domain is $\mathbb R$ it is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about $f(x) = 1/(1+x)^2$, then it is certainly not. Consider $x = 1,-3$.

If you are talking about $f(x) = x/(x^2 + 1)$, then it is not either. Observe that
$$f(0) = 0, f(1) = \frac{1}{2}, f(2) = \frac{2}{5}$$
Since $f$ is continuous, it must hit $\frac{2}{5}$ at some point inbetween $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. Therefore $f$ is not injective.